# React Using addEventListener("scroll", function()) and useState shows no transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, addeventlistener

I want to change background color of navigation gradually with transition like [this](https://demos.creative-tim.com/soft-ui-dashboard-pro-react/marketplace/#/dashboards/default)

`Article.js`

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Breadcrumbs from '@mui/material/Breadcrumbs';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import './Article.css';


export default function Article() {
  const [isScrolling, setScrolling] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      if (window.scrollY < 10) {
        setScrolling(false);
      } else {
        setScrolling(true);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [isScrolling]);

  function CreateBasicBreadcrumbs() {
    return (
      <div
        role="presentation"
        className={`pop-up ${isScrolling && 'active'}`}
      >
        <Breadcrumbs
          aria-label="breadcrumb"
          sx={{ marginLeft: 2, }}
        >
          <Link
            underline="hover"
            color="inherit"
            component={RouterLink}
            to={'/'}
          >
            Home
          </Link>
          <Typography color="text.primary">
            Articles
          </Typography>
        </Breadcrumbs>
      </div >
    );
  }

  return (
    <Grid
      container='true'
      direction='row'
      width='100%'
      sx={{
        paddingTop: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 249, 250)'
      }}
      onScroll={(e) => { console.log('scrolling') }}
    >
      <Grid
        item='true'
        xs={12}
        sm={12}
        md={12}
        lg={9}
        xl={7}
        sx={{
          paddingLeft: 5,
          height: '2000px',
        }}
      >
        <CreateBasicBreadcrumbs />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

`Article.css`

```
.pop-up {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.pop-up.active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

When I run these, class name 'active' is added to the [div] but its background color is changed quickly from rgb(248, 249, 250) to rgb(255, 255, 255).

I think this is because addEventListener changes isScrolling every scroll and rerenders the [div] element and its children. But I'm not sure.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define a Component like `CreateBasicBreadcrumbs` inside another component. If you do so, React thinks it is a different object on every render of `Article`, so `CreateBasicBreadcrumbs` will be unmounted before every rerender of `Article`, losing its state.

Simply move its definition outside `Article`, and pass `isScrolling` as prop down to it.

Comment: You are right and you saved my time!! It worked when I moved out `CreateBasicBreadcrumbs ` to outside `Article`. Thank you!